# vrep_ros_interface build failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. I'm running Ubuntu 16.4.3 on VMware 8 pro for MacOS Sierra.
2. I also install ROS Kinetic following the ROS tutorial at:  http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu following from step 1.1 to step 1.6.
3. Then I downloaded Vrep 3.4.0 from http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/downloads.html for pro edu linux version and extract it into my home directory.
4. Then I follow a tutorial to install vrep_ros_interface http://analuciacruz.me/articles/RosInterface_kinetic/
   However, I failed at step 4 after I git clone the vrep_ros_interface into my project_ws/src folder and trying to build it.
5. The error log I got is:

> 

```
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  5%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/srvcall.cpp[0m
[ 10%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/ros_srv_io.h[0m
[ 15%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/pub.cpp[0m
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigString
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigValue
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/SensorLevels
[ 20%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/sub.cpp[0m
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigString
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigValue
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/SensorLevels
[ 25%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/srvsrv.cpp[0m
[ 30%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/ros_msg_io.h[0m
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigString
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigValue
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/SensorLevels
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigString
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigValue
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/SensorLevels
[ 35%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/adv.cpp[0m
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigString
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigValue
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/SensorLevels
[ 40%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/ros_srv_io.cpp[0m
[ 45%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/srvcli.cpp[0m
[ 50%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/ros_msg_io.cpp[0m
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigString
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigValue
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/SensorLevels
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigString
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/ConfigValue
WARNING: bad msg: driver_base/SensorLevels
[ 50%] Built target generate_ros_code
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp[0m
[ 50%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus[0m
[ 50%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp[0m
[ 50%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py[0m
[ 50%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp[0m
[ 50%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs[0m
[ 50%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_eus[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs[0m
[ 50%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp[0m
[ 50%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp[0m
[ 50%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp[0m
[ 50%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_eus[0m
[ 50%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp[0m
[ 50%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus[0m
[ 50%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py[0m
[ 50%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs[0m
[ 50%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus[0m
[ 50%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_cpp[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_eus[0m
[ 50%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp[0m
[ 50%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs[0m
[ 50%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp[0m
[ 50%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs[0m
[ 50%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py[0m
[ 50%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py[0m
[ 50%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_lisp[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target roscpp_generate_messages_py[0m
[ 50%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_nodejs[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf_generate_messages_py[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py[0m
[ 50%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp[0m
[ 50%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py[0m
[ 50%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs[0m
[ 50%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus[0m
[ 50%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp[0m
[ 50%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus[0m
[ 50%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp[0m
[ 50%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp[0m
[ 50%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs[0m
[ 50%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target actionlib_generate_messages_py[0m
[ 50%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[ 55%] [34m[1mGenerating generated/stubs.cpp, generated/stubs.h[0m
running external/pycpp/pycpp
running external/pycpp/pycpp
no lua file defined. skipping lua_to_xml
no lua file defined. skipping gen_reference_xml
running xsltproc
no lua file defined. skipping gen_lua_calltips
running generate_notepadplusplus_xml
running generate_notepadplusplus_txt
running generate_deprecated_txt
[35m[1mScanning dependencies of target v_repExtRosInterface[0m
[ 60%] [32mBuilding CXX object CMakeFiles/v_repExtRosInterface.dir/src/vrep_ros_interface.cpp.o[0m
[01m[Kc++:[m[K [01;31m[Kinternal compiler error: [m[KKilled (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
CMakeFiles/v_repExtRosInterface.dir/build.make:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/v_repExtRosInterface.dir/src/vrep_ros_interface.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/v_repExtRosInterface.dir/src/vrep_ros_interface.cpp.o] Error 4
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:784: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/v_repExtRosInterface.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/v_repExtRosInterface.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268111/vrep_ros_interface-build-failed/) by [garygao92](https://answers.ros.org/users/31014/garygao92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [garygao92](https://answers.ros.org/users/31014/garygao92/) on 2017-08-04**:
I've been stuck in this step for couple days. Hope anyone can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This:

```
compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
```

This is most of the time an indication that your system has run out of (virtual) memory. See the myriad of questions about this error on embedded (ARM) platforms fi.

Seeing as you are running in a VM, I would take a look at the amount of memory that you have assigned to it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [garygao92](https://answers.ros.org/users/31014/garygao92/) on 2017-08-06**:
Thank you very much! I extended VM's memory from 1GB to 4GB and I am able to build the package.